# SQLiteQueryBuilder reverse sort order

Tags: android, sqlite

I use ContentProvider, and [SQLiteQueryBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html):

```
    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        qb.setTables(NEWS_TABLE);

        switch(sUriMatcher.match(uri)){
          case NEWS_ITEM_ID: qb.appendWhere(KEY_ID+ "=" + uri.getPathSegments().get(1));
                           break;
          default: break;
        }

        String orderBy;

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(sortOrder)) {
              orderBy = KEY_DATE;
            } else {
                /* ______  WANT TO REVERSE IT HERE _____ */
              orderBy = sortOrder;
            }
        Cursor c = qb.query(newsDB, 
                            projection, 
                            selection, selectionArgs, 
                            null, null, 
                            orderBy);

        c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

        return c;
    }
```

How do I use reverse sort order for query? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ORDER BY` clause in SQL may have ascending or descending order. By default ascending order is used. To set reversed sort order you need to add `DESC` keyword to the end of `ORDER BY` clause.

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(sortOrder)) {
    orderBy = KEY_DATE;
} else {
    /* ______  WANT TO REVERSE IT HERE _____ */
    orderBy = KEY_DATE + " DESC";
}
```